# Localdb bcryptkeyderivation error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, localdb

I built a Windows Forms app with Visual Studio and I am trying to install it on another Windows 7 computer with Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB.
After I start the app and try to “login”, I get an error from `sqlservr.exe` that says:

> cannot find entry point, bcryptkeyderivation, bcrypt.dll.

I tried it on another pc with Windows 10 and there were no errors.

Comment: some minor changes

Answer (score 1):

Your edit pretty much sums it up.

SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB isn't supported on Windows 7. The SqlLocalDB.msi installer for me but when I tried to start an instance it would give the "BCryptKeyDerivation could not be located" error. Anecdotally 2016 is supposedly not supported, but it installed and default instances run for me.

Per [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994) :

> **Supported Operating System**:
>
> Windows 10 , Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows
>   Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016

Some [additional information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448506(v=vs.85).aspx) indicating that you'll need at least Windows 8

> **BCryptKeyDerivation function**
>
> The BCryptKeyDerivation function derives a key without requiring a
>   secret agreement. It is similar in functionality to BCryptDeriveKey
>   but does not require a BCRYPT_SECRET_HANDLE value as input.
>
> **Minimum supported client**
>
> Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]
>
> **Minimum supported server**
>
> Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | UWP apps]